# Visual Basic Windows Forms App and capturing video

Tags: vb.net, video-capture, directx-11

I have a simple VB Forms based Shuffleboard scoreboard app. I would like to add two overhead live video feeds that show the two scoring areas. This is a one off program that will never see the outside of my basement. I have played with a couple of the available vidcap libraries but there is no way I can justify purchasing a license to get rid of the demo popups.

My C++ skills are near nonexistent and the VB App is well developed and very user friendly, so I really don't want to rebuild the project. All I really want is the background of the scoreboard to be the two video feeds. *(This is so that spectators can see the scoring area without having to stand at the table.)*

I have been toying with the DirectX libs and C++ using Visual Studio 19. I can achieve the two cam views but cannot find a way to incorporate that into VB. I cannot seem to get the DirectX extensions to expose themselves when I go back to VB. Is this even doable using Visual Basic or am I going to have to rebuild in C++?

Comment: You can reach out to C++ libraries from .net so it's just a case of putting the two functional apps togeather